# Request for community consensus on what the signature tag should mean to us

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to open a discussion on what we should make of the [signature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signature) since it appears to mean several things if you look over the [existing questions we have that currently use this tag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signature).

The clear use cases for this word on an Apple centric site would be as follows (feel free to edit this as needed):

- email signatures in various Mail client applications for OS X and iOS.
- handwriting capture or simulation tools using touch, stylus, mouse, etc..
- Preview app (among others) being able to use a camera / scanner to digitize and overlay a signature
- Apps or services designed to digitally sign a document to verify in some manner that a traceable entity has "approved" a specific version of a document. (Digital Notary services for real estate and contract comes to mind)
- code signing and public key cryptography where a [signature](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html#AEN136) is used to certify and/or timestamp a certain entity and a specific file so that others can verify that signing event.

I'd like to see if we have enough consensus to improve the tag wiki and summaries for [handwriting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handwriting), [signature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signature), [digital-signature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature), and [code-signing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-signing) as well as decide if we need additional tags to map out the "signature" space a bit on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Tags should only exist to help an audience of answerers find the questions they're looking for. I suspect there could exist an actual audience knowledgable about code signing / digital message signing who might be interested in finding and answering questions so tagged.

Maybe there's an audience for Digital Notary sorts of things; I could be persuaded.

There is no need for a signature tag referring to the bits at the end of an e-mail message separate from the tag for the mail program in question; no one is an expert in writing your name and contact information at the end of a message separate from knowing how to use e-mail programs well. If you're trying to figure out how to make program X use the `<blink>` tag in your signature, you don't need a signature expert, you need either an expert in that program, or in this case, better still, someone to ban you from ever using the internet again because the `<blink>` tag is evil.

The [signature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signature) space doesn't need to be mapped out; it needs to be killed off. Remove the tag from e-mail signatures and make [code-signing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-signing) and [signature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signature) both point to digital signature. Fewer tags = better.

Comment: 100% agree with this single sentence. `The signature space doesn't need to be mapped out; it needs to be killed off.` I disagree that signature needs to be synonimized however, I think it needs to just remain emptied out.

Comment: @JasonSalaz synonymizing was my attempt at compromise. The more tags we can kill off, the better :-)

Comment: Do you, or anyone else reading this, know if any other networks use tag synonyms to basically say "Don't use this tag on this site." ?

Comment: Sounds great. Unless someone comes along with a compelling argument to keep signature, I'll get a post explaining why and how we'll burninate it.